# Simplifying a Sum to GammaRegularized

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

It doesn't seem Mathematica will automatically simplify

```
Sum[Exp[-x] x^m / m!, {m,0,5}]
```

to

```
GammaRegularized[6,x]
```

Is there a way to coerce it to do so, or are such special cases of special functions currently beyond Mathematica? It can deduce that they're equal:

```
FullSimplify[Sum[Exp[-x] x^m / m!, {m,0,5}] == GammaRegularized[6,x]]
True
```

I'll add that Mathematica appears to deduce these expressions are equal by doing a FunctionExpand[]:

```
In[1]:= FunctionExpand[GammaRegularized[6,x]]                                             

                     2       3       4      5    6
        120 x + 120 x  + 60 x  + 20 x  + 5 x  + x
Out[1]= ------------------------------------------
                              x
                         120 E  x
```

Comment: Why do you think that a little-known special function `GammaRegularized[6,x]` is simpler than an elementary function `Sum[Exp[-x] x^m / m!, {m,0,5}]`? I don't think so.

Comment: It's basic enough that it has an inverse function implemented in Mathematica - InverseGammaRegularized. It's also of fundamental importance in the coupon collector's problem.

Comment: This notion seems to be know-how of WRInc (e.g. see  [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) and [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8) and [its search in Google](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=regularized+gamma+function&sxsrf=APq-WBtAhwP75IOmYq45yLKSf6dEwLJL8A%3A1648122469052&ei=ZVo8YtzqAqKWjgab_a7YBg&ved=0ahUKEwicscHS1t72AhUii8MKHZu-C2sQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=regularized+gamma+function&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgAEEcyBAgAEEcyBAgAEEcyBAgAEEcyBAgAEEcyBAgAEEcyBAgAEEcyBAgAEEc6BwgAEEcQsANKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQqw1Yqw1gmxNoAXACeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz) ).

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

If the [`Sum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html) were held or [`Inactive`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) to prevent its evaluation, then a replacement rule could be used.

```
grRule = {
   HoldForm[Sum[Exp[-z_] x^k_/(k_)!, {k_, 0, n_}]] :>
    GammaRegularized[n + 1, z],
   Inactive[Sum][Exp[-z_] x^k_/(k_)!, {k_, 0, n_}] :>
    GammaRegularized[n + 1, z]};

HoldForm[Sum[Exp[-x] x^m/m!, {m, 0, 5}]] /. grRule

(* GammaRegularized[6, x] *)

Inactive[Sum][Exp[-x] x^m/m!, {m, 0, 5}] /. grRule

(* GammaRegularized[6, x] *)

Inactive[Sum][Exp[-x] x^m/m!, {m, 0, n}] /. grRule

(* GammaRegularized[1 + n, x] *)
```

Answer (score 3):

For manipulating expressions by replacement rule, it is often easier to get a replacement accomplished by working from the bottom up.  If we solve the `GammaRegularized` identity for `x^n` (for a specific integer `n`), we can replace `x^n` by a suitable expression. The downside to working this way with a rule that is eager to be applied is that we don't want to replace all powers of `x`. So I constructed a rule that has a parameter that controls when it may be applied. (Perhaps one should add more controls with upper and lower limits on the degrees of the monomials to which it may be applied, but it works on the OP's example.)

```
grRule // ClearAll;
(* special cases *)
grRule[] := grRule[0];
grRule[x_^n0_Integer] := grRule[x, n0];
grRule[x_ : HoldPattern[_], -Infinity] := grRule[x, 0];
grRule[x_ : HoldPattern[_], Infinity] := {};
(* general call *)
grRule[x_ : HoldPattern[_], n0_Integer] := 
 z_^n_Integer?NonNegative /; n >= n0 && MatchQ[z, x] :> 
  E^z n! (GammaRegularized[n + 1, z] - Sum[z^k/k!, {k, 0, n - 1}]/E^z);
```

Various use cases:

```
Sum[Exp[-x] x^m/m!, {m, 0, 5}] /. grRule[5] // Simplify
(*  GammaRegularized[6, x]  *)

FullSimplify[Sum[Exp[-x] x^m/m!, {m, 0, 5}],
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, Simplify[# /. grRule[x^5]] &}]
(*  GammaRegularized[6, x]  *)
```

In this example, `Max@Cases[..]` finds the greatest power of `x`, to which `grRule` is applied:

```
FullSimplify[
 Normal@Series[Exp[x], {x, 0, 10}],
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, 
   Simplify[# /. grRule[x, Max@Cases[#, x^p_ :> p, {0, Infinity}]]] &}]
(*  E^x GammaRegularized[11, x]  *)
```